# I tried to find the user from the mongoose db

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my mongoose schema for `movieLibrary`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    movieName:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    movieCast:[{
        actor:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        actress:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }],
    yearOfRelease:{
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now
    },
    movieDirector:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    genre:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    rating:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('movieLibrary',movieSchema)
```

I want to find the movie detail by passing the actor name as a parameter

I tried this:-

```
const movies = await Movie.find({
  "movieCast": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "actor": actor
    }
   }
})
```

But i get empty array as the output , Can you help me what issue might have occured , I get the correct answer in robo 3T, but not getting in postman.

Comment: Hello Ammy, I have formatted your question to look more readable. Can you share more of your code regarding the API call.


Also if you have used robo3T there should be an export function to directly give you the javascript code for the query. Could you do that to confirm once?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in your implementation. I have done the same thing like you except I have hard coded the value in query itself. It's working fine for me.

Data which is available in DB,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed9c47b39d18ba11f4c8f10"),
    "movieName" : "Titanic",
    "movieCast" : [ 
        {
            "actor" : "Leonardo",
            "actress" : "Winslet"
        }
    ],
    "yearOfRelease" : ISODate("1994-04-01T23:20:19.199Z"),
    "movieDirector" : "James Cameroon",
    "genre" : "History",
    "rating" : 8.8
}
```

And the query impl,

```
    async test() {
        let result = await Test.find({
            "movieCast": {
              $elemMatch: {
                "actor": 'Leonardo'
              }
             }
          });
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
          return result;
    }
```

I think either you could have passed the wrong actor value or none is passed.